# OAuth consent screen shows "Verification: Published" but still showing as Unverified Developer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

We spent considerable time going through the OAuth verification process by Google. We passed and our status shows as verified -- see screenshot.

But users still see "Unverified Developer" and get security warnings emailed to them about us.

edit: see below

Answer (score 0):

Turns out removing our own app's access (from the user's perspective on account.google.com) and re-adding it again (by using the app and signing in again) fixed it. 
There must have been some old creds cached or something...